# Invalid index 0, size is 0 for a nested list

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

My problem is

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();
menus.get(0).get(0).setMenuName("asasdasd");
```

I created a setter for error but it still has a problem. I need to add approximately 100 menu names, 1000 `foodName` and 1000 `foodPrize`. How can I solve it?

```
public class Restaurant
{
@SerializedName("cacheVersion")
@Expose
public String cacheVersion;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public String name;
@SerializedName("desc")
@Expose
public String desc;
@SerializedName("phones")
@Expose
public List<String> phones = null;
@SerializedName("menus")
@Expose
public List<Menu> menus = null;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
public String image;


public class Menu
{
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("foods")
    @Expose
    public List<Food> foods = null;

    public void setMenuName(String namex)
    {
        this.name = namex;
    }
}


public class Food
{
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("desc")
    @Expose
    public String desc;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    public String price;
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you have a list of list and you have allocated memory for the one list, kindly allocate for nested list too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create objects before trying to access them :

```
List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();
menus.add(new ArrayList<Restaurant.Menu>()); // create a List for the first level
menus.get(0).add(new Restaurant.Menu()); // create object for the second level
menus.get(0).get(0).setMenuName("asasdasd"); // access them
```

Note that you have no value to make `Menu` an inner class.
You may simplify by doing it a nested class :

```
public static class Menu { ...}
```

As you may notice, a `List` of `List` is rather cumbersome to manipulate.
As alternative, you could create your own class to wrap this structure or use third party libraries to do that (Guava library or Apache Common) if it matches to your functional requirement.

---

As a side note, I wonder why you separate things that should be related to.

`Restaurant` is related to `Menu` according to your model.
You should so use `Restaurant` that contains a set of `Menu`s to store `Menu` objects.
You could also introduce parameterized constructor to ease `Restaurant` and `Menu` creations and fluent methods to chain menu adding.

It could give a client code such as :

```
private List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();

void test() {
    Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant("my restaurant").add(new Menu("a menu"))
                                                           .add(new Menu("another menu"));
    restaurants.add(restaurant);

    Menu menu = restaurants.get(0)
                           .getMenus()
                           .get(0);
}
```

Here the required changes in `Restaurant`:

```
public Restaurant add(Menu menu) {
    this.menus.add(menu);
    return this;
}

public Restaurant(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Menu> getMenus() {
    return menus;
}
```

And here in `Menu` :

```
public Menu(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: This works well. Also, I don't need setter for this code. Can this create a problem with this structure?

Comment: Yes you may. As alternative, you could create your own class to wrap this structure or you use third party libraries to do that (Guava library or Apache Common) if it matches to your functional requirement. I updated the answer with.

Comment: My first answer addressed only the technical error. I updated by taking into consideration the functional aspect. I hope it could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Firstly, i did object but I coundn't convert it to List<Restaurant.Menu>

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask food part. I tried it but I make a mistake. We created it until menus.get().get(). It is okey. Why food part has problem ?menus.get(0).get(0).foods.add(new Restaurant.Food());----menus.get(0).get(0).foods.get(0).name = "sadsad" ----- and price

Comment: on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162289/discussion-between-davidxxx-and-ozan1).

Answer (score 3):

You can set a value by simply calling

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();
menus.add(new List<Restaurant.Menu> ().add(new Restaurant.Menu().setMenuName("asasdasd")));
```

Comment: This code instantiates an interface (which is not valid) and adds a `void` return in a List (which is not valid either).

Comment: new Restaurant.Menu().setMenuName("asasdasd") this part wanted static class. I did it. Also, List<Restaurant.Menu> (). this part wants 'List' is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

As the old saying goes: *Give a man a fish, you feed him for a day, but teach a man to fish and he will eat for a lifetime.* So, when does the exception occur?

> Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

Your problem is due to be having an empty list with no elements - this being your outer list, hence

> Size is 0

and then you try to access the first element:

> Invalid index 0